# Download from URL on ssh connection

Tags: linux, url, ubuntu, ssh, download

I've a ssh connection between my pc(linux) and a server(linux). 
I want to download a file from URL inside the server.
I tried with the command  :
   firefox URL
And i get :
   Error: no display specified
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on ssh, use the following command-

curl -O http://website/filetodownload.txt
or use wget command

Answer (score 1):

Try out with wget http://example.com/xyz.txt 
it will work